# jQuery FileReader Multiple

Tags: jquery, filereader

I am new to scripting. I have an input file to add multiple. Once image is uploaded the names of each image will be displayed along with a cross so that user can delete or add more images. I also have a preview container to display the upload images preview which I wish to update whenever a user adds or deletes any image.

**Demo:**

https://codepen.io/alikhan999/pen/oqOLqP

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var bgRendered;
$('#PageBGimageBtn').on('change', function(){

 if( $(this).val().length ){
 var BGimageBtn = $(this);
 var inputFiles = this.files;
 //var inputFile = inputFiles[0];
 $(inputFiles).each(function(index) {
    var inputFile = inputFiles[index];
    
    if( inputFile.size < 2000000) {
        
        if ( inputFile.type === 'image/jpeg' || inputFile.type === 'image/png' || inputFile.type === 'image/gif'  ) {               
            var BGcontainer = '<div id="BG-'+index+'" class="imgName"><span>'+inputFile.name+'</span><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>';
            $(BGimageBtn).closest('.uploadBtn').append(BGcontainer);
            
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                bgRendered = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);
                var slideRendered = '<div id="slideBG-'+index+'" style="background-image:url('+bgRendered+')"></div>';
                $('#background').append(slideRendered);
            };
            

            
        } else {
            alert('Only Image files are allowed');  
        }
        
    } else {
        alert('Image should be less than 2MB');
    }
    
});
}

});
});
```

**Problems:**

1. Since its a multi-upload then how to alert the user which file has invalid file extension or is exceeding the limit of file size.
2. I do not know how to delete the specific image when its name is clicked and how to update the preview section accordingly when a user adds or removes any image.

Answer (score 1):

FileList interface is still not really programation friendly, in the sense that we don't really have a built-in way to modify it (append / splice).

So the best move is to get out of this interface as soon as you can. And to do so, you can use an Array, in which you will place your Files.

*Nota bene:  you don't state what you will do with these Files. But if you need to upload it, then since we got rid of the FileList, we will have to use AJAX to send these Files, and the FormData API, but this is for later.*

For how to let your user know that one the files is invalid, do it in your preview interface.

And since we're here, instead of storing Files directly in our array, you could also create a wrapper object around your files, which will also contain the preview elements you need.

Also note that you don't need a FileReader here. To load a Blob or File object in a webpage as if it came from a server, use the `URL.createObjectURL` method instead.

```js
var file_list = []; // our array that will hold all our FileWrappers
$('#inp').on('change', function(evt) {
  var wrapper;
  for(var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; i++) {
    wrapper = new FileWrapper(inp.files[i]);
    $('#preview').append(wrapper.el);
    file_list.push(wrapper);
  }
});

$('#upload').on('click', function(evt) {
  var files = file_list.filter(function isValid(wrapper) {
    return wrapper.isValid;
  }).map(function getFile(wrapper) {
    return wrapper.file;
  });
  var fd = new FormData();
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    fd.append('files[]', file);
  });
    
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('post', 'your_server_address');
//  xhr.send(fd);
// won't work in SO snippets so we log their values instead
  for([key, value] of fd.entries()) {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
});
  
    

function FileWrapper(file) {
  this.isValid = isValid(file);
  this.file = file;
  var remove = this.remove.bind(this);
  this.el = initElements();

  function isValid(file) {
    return file &&
      file instanceof Blob &&
      file.type.indexOf('image/') === 0 &&
      file.size &&
      file.size < 200000;
  }
  function initElements() {
    var el = $('<div>', {class:'file-wrapper'}).append(
      $('<button>', {text: 'x'})
        .on('click', remove),
      $('<p>', {class:'file-name', text: file.name || 'no name'}),
      $('<img>', {src: URL.createObjectURL(file), alt: 'invalid file'})
        .on('error', toggleInvalid)
    );
   if(this.invalid) {
    toggleInvalid();
   }
   return el;
   function toggleInvalid() {
     el.addClass('invalid');
   }
 }      
}
FileWrapper.prototype = Object.create({
  remove: function() {
    var index = file_list.indexOf(this);
    if(index > -1) {
      file_list.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.el.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.input-wrapper > input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#preview {
  vertical-align : top;
}
.file-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 2px;
}
.file-wrapper.invalid{
  color: red;
}
.file-wrapper p{
  margin: 0;
  max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.file-wrapper button{
  float: right;
}
.file-wrapper img{
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper"><input type="file" id="inp" multiple><span>add new files</span></div>
<button id="upload">upload to server</button>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: Friend I am trying to create an interface where user can select the images he want for the slideshow. The actual preview will be a running slideshow that will be updating on images added or removed. Finally all images will be added to a zip file using the utility of jsZip

Comment: Same pattern applies. Move the Files in your FileList to an Array and work from the Array.

Comment: Friend I modified my demo to actually show what i wish to do. https://codepen.io/alikhan999/pen/oqOLqP

Since my codes have no Array to store the files I am able to update my slides whenever a new image is added but not when an image is been removed

Comment: I also created a new demo with your codes but I have no idea how to create slides with images with your code and also to manage the slides whenever images are added or deleted. Demo: https://codepen.io/alikhan999/pen/pLBMrW

Comment: I do need a filereader at some point weather in the slide image src or preview image src so that later jsZip can render that image data into a new image.